# Accessing private value of iterator in surrounding class

Tags: c++

Check out this simplified example code:

```
class Foo {
private:
    struct bar {
        int private_value;  // only used for internal stuff of class Foo

        int public_value;
    };
public:
    class iterator {
    public:
        iterator(Foo::bar* c)
            :curr{ c }
        {
        }

        int& operator*() { return curr->public_value; }
        int* operator->() { return &curr->public_value; }
    private:
        Foo::bar* curr;
    };


    void some_function();
};

void Foo::some_function()
{
    Foo::iterator it = get_iterator();  // get an iterator from function

    *it //  this gives only curr->public_value
        //  what to add to iterator to have acces  of private value from iterator class?
}
```

I want to use the iterator in a function and get the `private_value` out of it. Is there any way to make a function in the iterator so only the class Foo can access `private_value` from the iterator? I cant allow to return the whole *bar structure in the Iterator since only `public_value` is intended to be accesible fpr the user of `foo`

Comment: You can declare Foo a friend class. You might have to declare iterator outside of Foo for that to work though. I don't remember.

Comment: I'm thinking `private` functions in `iterator` and a `friend` relationship between `iterator` and `Foo`.

Comment: It is possible, but ***why?***. Because this sounds like an XY problem. Usually it is not necessary to expose the internals of the iterator. It sounds like your trying to fix something, maybe not in the best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just making the surrounding class friend in iterator works:

```
class Foo {
private:
    struct bar {
        int private_value;  // only used for internal stuff of class Foo

        int public_value;
    };
public:
    class iterator {
    public:
        iterator(Foo::bar* c)
            :curr{ c }
        {
        }

        int& operator*() { return curr->public_value; }
        int* operator->() { return &curr->public_value; }
    private:
        Foo::bar* curr;

        friend class Foo;           // friend
    };

    void some_function();
};
```

sometimes you don't see the forest in the woods...